# Django ORM add variable instead .filter directive

Tags: django, python-3.x, orm

In my project i have a function with  django ORM query inside.
I would to pass into the .filter parth a list o values passed to the function:

```
def testFilter(filterlist):
    #for example filterlist could be: thread='DEAD',id=11,t_type='SA'
     myquery = t_threads.objects.filter(filterlist).select_related().order_by(lorder)[x:y]
```

but if i , for example run my function:

```
testFilter("id=1,thread='LIVE'")
```

i got an error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

How i can run my ORM query passing the filter directive every time i run the function?

So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use `kwargs` for that:

```
def testFilter(**kwargs):
     myquery = t_threads.objects.filter(**kwargs)...

testFilter(id=1, thread='LIVE')
```